# Android onUpgrade Database causing IllegalStateException

Tags: android

in my `dbHelper`:

```
onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

function I save one table to an external database.

Therefore I

1. attach and copy to the external database
2. delete the db file in this function and copy it from external
3. restore from external database to db.

this works until the function returns to getWritableDatabase()

Here I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no transaction pending
```

What is wrong? Thanks
Tata

Comment: Please post the relevant code and Logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `onUpgrade` method (as well as `onCreate`) occurs within a transaction, and at the end sets the transaction to be successful and ends it.

However, you have already ended the transaction in `onUpgrade`, resulting in this error.

Relevant code from `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
        ...
        if (version != mNewVersion) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                if (version == 0) {
                    onCreate(db);
                } else {
                    onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                }
                db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: I do some sql attaching which cannot be done within a transaction. therefore I db.endTransaction(); That was the problem. Now I call db.beginTransaction(); at the end of onUpgrade. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you probably called `SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction()` in `onUpgrade` without first calling `SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()`. Though it's a bit hard to tell without seeing any code ;)